# 413 Request Entity Too Large IIS 10

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, devops

I'm trying to send an object that contains 4 files (as base64 string) to a WebApi 2 as Http Post request. however, on execution, I get `413 Error` on the server. on local its all good and working.

So I went ahead and used this [Tutorial](https://port135.com/2019/03/16/http-status-413-request-entity-too-large/) and changed the `uploadReadAheadSize` to `1048576000` however I still get the same error.

More clues! funny thing is that if I upload another object that has a bigger size than this it'll work on the server. so I thought maybe it's not because of `uploadReadAheadSize`.. but I don't know what else can cause this issue. any thoughts?

Comment: How big are the files?

Comment: @Neil the string length of my JSON is 1099830

Comment: Have you tried increasing maxRequestEntityAllowed  as well?

Comment: @LjubomirBacovic it's set on `4294967295` is it enough?

Comment: How long it takes to return the 413 error?  Have you tried to recycle the application pool ? Because sometimes configuration will not take effect if you don't recycle it. Besides, if you post call fiddler. it should return the error stack trace in response body. Did you see what the error stack trace  looks like? If  uploadReadAheadSize is not working in this case, capturing and analyzing dump file for first chance exception would be the first step to troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by  [adding the web.config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78YMJ.jpg)

and adding this code.

```xml
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="144400000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>   
    ...
</system.webServer>
```